# How to pass data from a view to another view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, list, swiftui

I'm dealing with a big problem and i tried in many ways to fix this, but really didn't find the right answear.

Basically, I have a list with food menus, and when I'm tapping on them, I want to show the content of them like energy, protein, fats, carbohydrates etc ,but all is shown is somed ID's. There is a tricky thing in my backend.

I'l put the code bellow and I will explain it step by step :

This is where the food menus are : [Food menus photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8ltK.png)

```
List {
            Section(header: Text(Texts.meniuriViewText1)) {
                    ForEach(syncViewModel.menu.filter({$0.type == 1359})) { men in
                    HStack {
                        NavigationLink(destination: ItemMenuView(meniu: men)) {
                       Image("healthyMeal")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            .padding()
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                            Text(men.name)
                                .font(.system(size: 16))
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            HStack {
                                Text("\(men.price) lei")
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                
                                Text("\(men.ingredients[0].grams, specifier: "%.0f")g")
                                    .font(.system(size: 16))
                                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                        Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                .font(.title)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.onboardingColor)
                                .padding(20)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    coreDataViewModel.addTask(name: men.name, grams: men.ingredients[0].grams, price: Int(men.price))
                                }
                        }
       
                }
                
            }
}
```

This is the details about food menus : [Details photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDyJy.png)

```
var meniu : Meniuri?

var body: some View {
  VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Ingrediente")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .padding(30)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    ForEach(meniu!.ingredients) { men in
                        HStack(spacing: 15) {
                            
                            Image("aubergine")
                                .padding(.leading, 30)
                            
                            Text("\(men.ingredient)")
                                .foregroundColor(.colorGrayDark)
                            
                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(men.grams, specifier: "%.0f")g")
                                .foregroundColor(.colorGrayDark)
                                .padding(.trailing, 30)
                            
                        }
                    }
                        .padding(.bottom, 15)
}
```

This is my menu Model "Meniuri" :

```
struct Meniuri: Codable, Identifiable{

let id: Int
    let meta: ExtrasOptionMeta
    let name: String
    let ingredients: [Ingredients]
    let type, price: Int

}

struct Ingredients: Codable, Identifiable{
    var id: Int { ingredient }
    let ingredient: Int
    let grams: Double
}
```

Now to explain, "ingredient" property from Ingredients Model is "Item-Linked" in my backend with this Ingredient Model , so ingredient property from Ingredients is basically id from Ingredient Model. How can I access the ingredients from Ingredient model in my "details about food menus" ?

```
struct Ingredient: Model, Identifiable {
    static var itemName: String = "ingredient"
    var id: Int
    var meta: Meta
    var name: String
    var energy: Double
    var protein, fats, carbohydrates, fiber: Double?
    var saturatedFats, sugar, monosaturatedFats, polysaturatedFats: Double?
    var cholesterol, calcium: Int?
    var iron, magnesium: Double?
    
}
```

This is how I'm retrieving the data from the internet :

```
 func fetchMenus() {
        _spaceOne.fetch(path: "/api/items", parameters: ["q" : "at'test' select item from 'menu'"]) { result in
            switch result {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
            break
        case .success(_, let data, _):
            do{
                let meniu = try JSONDecoder().decode([Meniuri].self, from: data)
                    self.menu = meniu
            
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            break
        }
        }
    }


func fetchIngredients ()  {
        _spaceOne.fetch(Ingredient.self).all{ result in
            switch result {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
            break
            case .success(let ingred):
                self._ingredient = ingred
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: I think all the swiftui code is irrelevant to the question, this is about your data source and how to structure you model data. I don't understand how you actually fetch the ingredients but one solution could be to load all ingredients into a cache (dictionary) and retrieve them from there using the id property as a key. Another option is to _not_ use the model you get from the back end but instead to map it into another model where you replace `Ingredients` objects with `Ingredient` ones and perhaps do some other changes to make the model more useful for you.

Comment: I said it was all about the model layer in my  previous comment but you might also consider using some view model or controller class(es) between the model and the view depending on what path you take.

Comment: Hello @JoakimDanielson. First of all, thank you for your answer. All the Networking func like the ones in this post for fetching the ingredients and the menu are in a View Model.

Second : How can i map to another model to replace Ingredients with Ingredient ?

Comment: That is hard for me to answer since it is not clear how you fetch your data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple example of it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
          NavigationLink(destination: FeatureView1(title: "FeatureView1")) {
            Text("Go to FeatureView1")
          }
      }
  }
}

struct FeatureView1 : View {
  var title: String

  var body: some View {
     Text(title)
     NavigationLink(destination: FeatureView2(title: "FeatureView2")) {
        Text("Go to FeatureView2")
     }
  }
}

struct FeatureView2 : View {
  var title: String

  var body: some View {
     Text(title)
  }
}
```

There are many other ways to share datas between views according to your use case, I let you see @EnvironmentObject, @Binding etc later